# What's wrong with this drawable?

Tags: android-view, android-drawable

Having a drawable,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="-90"
    android:startColor="#00000000"
    android:centerColor="#00000000"
    android:endColor="#eefff000"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

when using as

```
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/title_bk"
            />
```

it got an error:

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:19790)
```

but using "#66000000" instead of the drawable it is fine

```
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#66000000"
            />
```

Why?

Comment: Can you share the complete log of your error please? It might be throwing some other exception like OutOfMemory, how big is the drawable?

Comment: that is what the error log shows. If change to` android:background="#66000000"` it works fine, as soon as change to `android:background="@drawable/title_bk"`, it crashes, all the time.